# Vaadin 14 - Unable to compute frontend dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, production, vaadin14

I am building a Springboot-Vaadin application, using Vaadin 14.8.4, gradle-vaadin plugin 0.14.8.1 on macOS 12.2.1.
After some changes to the backend code (not even touching any Vaadin related code), any attempt to build the application with
`./gradlew clean build -Pvaadin.productionMode`
results in the error

```
Execution failed for task ':vaadinBuildFrontend'.
> Unable to compute frontend dependencies
```

Adding the debug option to gradle does not reveal additional information. Building the application without the `-Pvaadin.productionMode` switch works okay. This behaviour appeared before quite frequently, but could be resolved by removing all Vaadin generated artifacts. Now I am stuck with the error.

How can I package the app for production without running into the error? Or, at least, how can I find more information about the problem?

Comment: It sounds like what is failing is running "npm install" to install dependencies from npm. You could try to run this manually and maybe get the error output that tells what the actual problem is

Comment: I did a npm install before - still the aforementioned error shows up

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-gradle-plugin/issues/116

Comment: After a lot of experimenting I found that the problem does not occur (at least until now) when using plain gradle instead of the gradle wrapper. After reconfiguring Intellij to use the local gradle installation, the problem went away.
NB: this does not help for my CI/CD server though, as that has to use gradle wrapper.